# Azure Devops change message after build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Is there a way to change message after build?
I want to have more specific message than just "build succeded".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change message after build?

No, you cannot change the message after build.

The build result is read-only and cannot be updated after the build is completed.